# InfoPath forms 2010 in SharePoint 2016

Tags: infopath

What would be the limitations if I am migrating from 2010 to 2016 in terms of InfoPath forms. Initially I have migrated from 2010 to 2016 in my test environment and the forms are showing fine with the workflows are also being working well without any issues. If this is the case what does it mean SP 2016 we cannot work on InfoPath? Does that mean we cannot create new InfoPath any more or we cannot use the existing InfoPath forms from 2010 to 2016? I am really perplexed with no article out is saying clear instructions even MS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade InfoPath 2010 to 2013 and that should work fine with SharePoint 2016

Answer (score 2):

Everything with InfoPath works in SharePoint 2016 as it did with SharePoint 2010. It's a fully supported product until SharePoint 2016 is end of life.

Comment: does that mean sp2019 won't include infopath?

Comment: We do not know that yet, but it's a good possibility.

Comment: Hi Trevor is there any article that says InfoPath 2016 will continue to work and whatever changes we want to do to forms can be done as same as SP2010? Can I refer to any article on that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no article that states something as explicit as that.